# running multiple tasks asynchronously and adding new ones to the task list as tasks finish

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Apologies for the bad title, I'm not sure how to succinctly describe this.

I'm building a service in .net core to process files. The general idea would be to (in a loop) check for new tasks to run on a file by using a DB call, and if found, fire them off async. There would be a throttler to limit the number of running tasks. If it hit the limit, it would just wait until a task is finished before firing off a new one. If the DB call returns nothing, then it would just sleep for a bit and try again later.

Fairly basic I think, but I'm running into issues because everything I've read says you should always await a task and not "fire and forget". But if I do that, then I'm left either running files synchronously or batching them. I'm missing something I'm sure.

Currently it's implemented as a IHostedService (BackgroundService specifically). Here us the main ExecuteAsync method that does the work. Implemented as fire and forget. (Visual studio gives the "call not awaited" warning on Task.Run)

```
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        var throttleTimeout = 10000;
        //set up semaphore
        var taskThrottler = new SemaphoreSlim(10, 10);          

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {

            //wait for free slot
            await taskThrottler.WaitAsync(throttleTimeout,stoppingToken);

            //get next file to process
            var currentFile = await _fileService.GetNextFileForProcessing();

            // create task
            Task.Run( async
                () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //do work with file tracker
                        var result  = await _fileProcessorController.ProcessFile(currentFile);

                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        taskThrottler.Release();
                    }
                }                    
                , stoppingToken);


        }
    }
```

Now if I change that and tack on an await before Task.Run, then I'm (essentially) running synchronously because each task will be awaited before the next is fired..

If I add the tasks to a list I can use "await Task.WhenAll(tasks);". But then I'm batching.

I need to be able to gracefully handle failed processing jobs, so an await in some form is a must I think.

All the examples I've found that tackle a similar problem usually have the list of tasks (or files) to do in advance, and then just iterate through. But I'm not sure what the best method is when I need to add tasks to the list while processing others.

Perhaps something that uses a task list and WhenAny? And then can I add new tasks to the task list on each loop if any are found?

Comment: You really shouldn't alter the list you are iterating over.  LINQ will usually throw an exception if you even try to do this.  There are ways around that exception but even then it is just a bad idea.

Comment: Agreed with Bill. Consider re-designing your code if you need to inject some new task. If you REALLY want to do this then maybe consider using 2 lists, one for your original Tasks and one for your new tasks. If you must nest further than that then consider looking into some rules engine like the Rete Algorithm https://github.com/NRules/NRules

Comment: Why are you opposed to the `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` "batching" approach.  That seems like probably the simplest solution.  Get up to `n` of them, process them, rinse repeat.

Comment: I'm not opposed to it in theory, but if any of the tasks are long running, then the whole batch gets held up waiting.